# How to remove title field from content edit page?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

i want remove field title in any content type on drupal 7. i use module display suite and hidden title but when i add new content that "title is required .......................................... ". thank you for help.

[image]

i want remove title field in any content type.

Comment: Hi, in the future for the `Question` just ask your question. do not write "hi I have a question" ... of course you have a question, that's why you are writing here :D. Just ask it. I have editing your writing to make it more clear for readers.

Answer (score 5):

You want to either:

- Remove the `title` field completely using the Fields UI. [See this documentation page on the Fields UI](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui). If you *really* don't want a title then just remove the field from the content type.
- Use the [Automatic Nodetitle](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module to create a `title` from a Token and hide the title in Edit Forms.
- If not a Node, use the [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module to create a `title` and then hide it from users in the Edit forms.

In general most content types *need* a `title`. Titles are the **Names** we give content to find them using Search forms and pages.